# Flutter ios app - Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRHeartbeatInfo?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRHeartbeatInfo

*Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)*

```
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.5
  firebase_core: ^2.8.0
  firebase_core_web: ^2.2.1
```

Flutter app showing this error.

**Podfile**

```
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: did you found soultion yet?

Comment: I did not find solution , But alternative solution is

downgrade the following plugins

  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.8
  firebase_core: ^1.21.1
  firebase_core_web: ^1.7.3 to this version

Comment: Let me know whether works r not

Comment: i have different case. i was using FirebaseFirestore. i tried playing with the version by downgrading it but it didn't work. but luckily it turns out that it is unused dependency  so i remove it and now it solved.

Comment: Anyone found the solution? Facing it today

Comment: Found the solution here: https://leancode.co/blog/flutter-firebase-plugins-linking-error

Answer (score 1):

I had same error and when I deleted extra lines from my Podfile (target 'Runner' do - section), `Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRHeartbeatInfo?` error disappeared.

In your case you can try to delete `pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'`  from your Podfile. So it will looks like this

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```